# How to get "window.location.hostname", "window.location.href" and "document.title" from Chrome extension

Tags: php, google-chrome

I guys, I'm building a Chrome extension, and I need to get

1. `window.location.hostname`
2. `window.location.href`
3. `document.title`

when the user clicks the extension's icon.

I've already added the "tabs" permission on the "manifest" file, but I still cannot get any of these string.

I've even followed the instructions that can be found at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

But I still cannot understand the syntax of the code I have to write.

I just want my extension to save the above information about the tab when its icon is clicked and then send them to another PHP page, something like this:

```
var url=window.location.hostname;
var link=window.location.href;
var title=document.title; 

window.open("http://www.mywebsite.com/print.php?url=" + url + "&link="+link + "&title="+title);
```

Comment: You need to encode your variables for the URL.

Comment: Yeah I know, thanks anyway. I've just posted this code for example purpose.